# What would be the type signature of a function that can be applied both like (& f %~) and (^. f) where operators are from Lens library?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, type-signature

I have a function that gets a value from a record and sets it to the same field in a different record.

What I want to do is understand how the mechanisms behind it works

```
setToPercent perc basedOn toSetOn = setStat
    where baseStat = basedOn ^. _func -- type is Maybe Float
          percentDelta = (\a -> perc * a) <$> baseStat -- Maybe Float
          setStat = toSetOn & _func %~ (\a -> (+) <$> a <*> percentDelta)
```

Where `_func` is defined as `MyDataType -> Maybe Float` (default function from record syntax.)

And it works just like I expect it to. What I want to know is `_func`'s type signature.

I know here `basedOn ^. _func`, `_func` would have the type 
`Getting (f0 Float) MyDataType (f0 Float)`

and here `toSetOn & _func %~ (\a -> (+) <$> a <*> percentDelta`, `_func` would have the type `ASetter Weapon Weapon (f0 Float) (f0 Float)`
where data `Weapon` and `MyDataType` are basically the same data type with identical constructors.

But I'm not sure what would be the overall type.
As in what would be the function type if I were to generalize `setToPercent` w.r.t `_func` as in

```
setToPercent fnToApply perc basedOn toSetOn = setStat
    where baseStat = basedOn ^. fnToApply -- type is Maybe Float
          percentDelta = (\a -> perc * a) <$> baseStat -- Maybe Float
          setStat = toSetOn & fnToApply %~ (\a -> (+) <$> a <*> percentDelta)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question!

> I know here `basedOn ^. _func`, `_func` would have the type  `Getting (f0 Float) MyDataType (f0 Float)`
>
> and here `toSetOn & _func %~ (\a -> (+) <$> a <*> percentDelta`, `_func` would have the type  `ASetter Weapon Weapon (f0 Float) (f0 Float)`

So, informally, `_func` is both a getter and a setter. Looking at the diagram on [the lens homepage on Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) or the one on [the *Glassery* blogpost](http://oleg.fi/gists/posts/2017-04-18-glassery.html) by Oleg Grenrus, the "least common ancestor" of getters and setters is lenses.

The lens library proposes at least two representations of lenses, a polymorphic one `Lens' Weapon (f0 Float)` (the definition contains a `forall`) and a monomorphic one `ALens' Weapon (f0 Float)` (that replaces the `forall` with a concrete functor).

Since we expect here `_func` to automatically specialize to `ASetter` and `Getting`, one straightforward way is to use the polymorphic one (this requires `RankNTypes` if `_func` is a parameter rather than a toplevel binding).

```
_func :: Lens' Weapon (f0 Float)   -- Polymorphic
      -- specializes to
      :: Getting (f0 Float) Weapon (f0 Float)
      :: ASetter' Weapon (f0 Float)
```

There is another way using the monomorphic version. I find this more idiomatic when `_func` is a function parameter, as it makes it easier for callers to pass in a suitable argument. However, we must then explicitly generalize `_func` when we actually use it.

```
_func :: ALens' Weapon (f0 Float)   -- Monomorphic

cloneLens _func :: Lens' Weapon (f0 Float)  -- Polymorphic again

-- The ALens' type synonym usually appears in argument position
myFun :: ALens' Foo Bar -> MyResult
myFun _func = ...

-- Example usage
basedOn ^. cloneLens _func
toSetOn & cloneLens _func %~ ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Both version work perfectly! Also I had to add `(Functor f0, Applicative f0)` to the context of the type to permit the use of `<$>`, `<+>` & `<*>`.